# how to install laravel?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-7

I am having an error trying to install laravel globally.

When I write `composer global require laravel/installer`
I get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.4.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.38
    - laravel/installer v3.1.0 requires symfony/console ^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.10, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.11, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.12, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.13, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.14, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.15, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.8, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.0.9, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.10, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.11, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.12, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.8, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.9, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.10, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.11, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.12, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.8, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.2.9, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.10, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.11, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.8, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.3.9, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.4.8, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.0, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.1, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.2, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.3, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.4, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.5, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.6, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.7, v3.4.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v5.0.8, v3.4.38].
    - Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.4.38) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.4.38].

composer version: 1.10.0
php version: PHP 7.4.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v3.4.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.4.38
```

You need to either remove or upgrade `symfony/console`. To [remove](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove) it, run `composer global remove symfony/console`.

Comment: ...to remove `symfony/console`, you don't have to remove the installer ;)

Answer (score 13):

Run your command with following additional parameters:

```
composer global require laravel/installer --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

The command that should actually be run is

```
composer global require laravel/installer --update-with-dependencies
```